# Open URLs in Google Chrome and resize windows

Tags: macos, google-chrome, command-line, macros, launching-application

I've got a few monitoring sites set up for my mobile apps (e.g. crittercism) and I have an extra monitor set up for monitoring everything.  I have a few Chrome windows sized down to just the values I'm interested in and spaced so that everything fits on the screen.

I'd like to write a macro that launches all (at this point 8 sites) these Chrome/browser windows and spaces them accordingly.

Rebooting and resizing right now is a pain.

Comment: Some quick googling turned up Breeze, a window manager which allows you to save state. http://autumnapps.com/breeze/index.html

Comment: 'Properly written' applications store their state automatically; I guess in this case the cross-platfom middleman isn't behaving properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript. Save the following code as a .html file:

```html
<html>
<script>
function openWindows() {
  window1=window.open('http://google.com/','','width=400,height=300');
  window1.moveTo(0, 0);
  window2=window.open('http://yahoo.com/','','width=400,height=200');
  window2.moveTo(0, 300);
  window3=window.open('about:blank','','width=200,height=500');
  window3.moveTo(400, 0);
};
</script>
<button onclick="openWindows();">Open Windows</button>
</html>
```

Open it in your browser and click the button. You should see something like this:

[image: Multiple popups]

NB: You'll probably have to relax your popup blocker settings. Here's how to change the popup settings on Chrome:
[image: Chrome popup settings]
This won't change popup blocker settings for other websites.

On Mac, an extra monitor extends the screen size. For example, if your secondary monitor is arranged to the left of the primary monitor, `window4.moveTo(-300, 0);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're interested in [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html). So you could `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app` or you could similarly `open http://www.google.com`. You can also use AppleScript to position windows automatically, including directly from the command line via [osascript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) — see e.g. [this answer on the Linux & Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39900/using-terminal-mac-os-x-to-move-position-of-an-applications-window).

Comment: still might checkout the osascript, but javascript gets me where i need to be.